# how to get output of rb_backtrace() in gdb for passenger process

Tags: ruby, gdb

I'm trying to dump a backtrace of a passenger process in gdb. I know I should just execute

```
attach <PID>
call rb_backtrace()
```

after starting gdb, but I can't figure out where the output is going, I've looked at rails production logs (set to info), nginx logs in /var/logs/nginx but I can't find the output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer on the ruby end -- I'd guess it is going to the ruby process' stdout or stderr -- but gdb recently got a new feature that is designed to help with this scenario.

The new feature is called "frame filters" and it lets you change how stack traces are presented by writing simple Python scripts that examine the state of the inferior process.  For example, you could write such a script that understands the Ruby interpreter, and then have gdb's "bt" automatically interleave interpreted (Ruby) frames with C frames.

For more information, start here and read the next few nodes: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Frame-Filter-API.html#Frame-Filter-API

I'd like to see this feature be adopted by the various interpreter projects.  There's been pretty good adoption of pretty printing, and I think this is a logical next step.